# How to set Antialiasing -> False on legend frame

Tags: plotting, legending, rendering, antialiasing

The legend box has antialiasing by default.  How can it be switched off?

```
ListLinePlot[Table[f, {f, {Log[x], x^(1/2)}}, {x, 0, 10, 0.1}],
 DataRange -> {0, 10}, Frame -> True,
 PlotLegends -> 
  Placed[LineLegend[{"log(x)", "x^(1/2)"},
    LegendFunction -> (Framed[#, FrameStyle -> (Antialiasing -> False)] &)],
   {{0.5, 0.1}, {0, 0}}]]
```

[image]

[image]

By contrast, the old `PlotLegends` package produces a nice crisp legend frame.

```
Quiet[<< PlotLegends`];
ListLinePlot[Table[f, {f, {Log[x], x^(1/2)}}, {x, 0, 10, 0.1}],
 DataRange -> {0, 10}, Frame -> True,
 PlotLegend -> Map[Style[#, 12] &, {"log(x)", "x^(1/2)"}],
 LegendSize -> {0.45, 0.3}, LegendPosition -> {0., -0.4},
 LegendShadow -> None, LegendTextSpace -> 2]
```

[image]

Comment: I couldn't understand your question at first because on my screen it is very hard to see what you mean.  Here's a smaller example that demonstrates the problem better: `Magnify[Rasterize[
  Graphics[Text[Framed["abcd\nxyzt"]], ImageSize -> 80], "Image"], 5]`. Your example also effectively uses `Framed` inside of an `Inset`.

Comment: Maybe you could export your plot as a PDF file?

Comment: What version are you on? It seems to work in v11.

Comment: @M.R. I'm on v11.0.1 on Windows 10.